# CuFFT Timing Constraint

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I am new to CUDA and I am trying to perform FFT on my GPU using CuFFT library. The problem is, when I run the compiled code first time it takes around 500us but if I run it again immediately without waiting it takes around 175us. (I am running the .exe from cmd). Whenever I give some pause it takes 500us to compute the FFT. For different NX-point DFT it gives me almost the same timing. I am computing the time from start of FFT to end, not the data copying time. Can anyone please tell me what is the problem. What I was expecting was to have higher execution time for high NX-point FFT, but it is taking almost the same time. Attached below is my code.

I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express and CUDA v6.0. System specs: Corei7 3.60Ghz, RAM: 16GB, GPU: GeForce GT640 (Using same GPU for displaying and Computation)

Any suggestions and help would be appreciated.

```
// Raw Data Generation
#define TABLE_SIZE 1000
#define TWO_PI (3.14159 * 2)
#define CYCLES 20
#define NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES (TABLE_SIZE*CYCLES)

// FFT Values 
#define NX 2048  // NX-point DFT
#define BATCH 1 

// Sine Generator Function 
void sin_func(float *sample_ptr)
{ 
    float phaseIncrement = TWO_PI/TABLE_SIZE;
    float currentPhase = 0.0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < CYCLES*TABLE_SIZE; i ++){
        *sample_ptr = sin(currentPhase);
        sample_ptr = sample_ptr + sizeof(float)/4;
        currentPhase += phaseIncrement;
    }
}


void main() 
{   
const int ARRAY_SIZE = NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES*sizeof(float);
const int FFT_OUT_SIZE = sizeof(cufftComplex)*(NX/2+1)*BATCH;

// Variable Declaration for execution time computation
    LARGE_INTEGER ticksPerSecond;
    LARGE_INTEGER startTick;   // A point in time
    LARGE_INTEGER starttime;   // For converting tick into real time        
    LARGE_INTEGER endTick;   // A point in time
    LARGE_INTEGER endtime;   // For converting tick into real time          

    // get the high resolution counter's accuracy
     QueryPerformanceFrequency(&ticksPerSecond);
//


// Initialization of input data on Host
float h_rawdata[NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES];
float h_checkdata[NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES];

sin_func(&h_rawdata[0]);
// Display values in the resulting array
for (int i =0; i < 12 ; i++) {
    printf("%f", h_rawdata[i]);
    printf(((i % 4) != 3) ? "\t" : "\n");
}


//Initializing output array on Host
cufftComplex h_fftout[FFT_OUT_SIZE];

//Allocate memory on GPU
float *d_rawdata;
float *d_checkdata;
cufftHandle plan; 
cufftComplex *d_fftout;

cudaMalloc((void**)&d_rawdata, ARRAY_SIZE);
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_checkdata, ARRAY_SIZE); // For Testing Only
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_fftout, FFT_OUT_SIZE);

//copying data to device(GPU) memory
cudaMemcpy (d_rawdata, h_rawdata, ARRAY_SIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

// ** Doing FFT ** //
    if (cudaGetLastError() != cudaSuccess){
    fprintf(stderr, "Cuda error: Failed to allocate\n"); 
    return; 
} 
if (cufftPlan1d(&plan, NX, CUFFT_R2C, BATCH) != CUFFT_SUCCESS){
    fprintf(stderr, "CUFFT error: Plan creation failed"); 
    return; 
}   

// fft starting
QueryPerformanceCounter(&startTick);  // Time stamp at start of FFT

//if (cufftExecR2C(plan, (cufftReal*)d_rawdata, d_fftout) != CUFFT_SUCCESS){ 
if (cufftExecR2C(plan, d_rawdata, d_fftout) != CUFFT_SUCCESS){ 
    fprintf(stderr, "CUFFT error: ExecC2C Forward failed"); 
    return; 
} 
if (cudaDeviceSynchronize() != cudaSuccess){ 
    fprintf(stderr, "Cuda error: Failed to synchronize\n"); 
return; 
} 
QueryPerformanceCounter(&endTick); // Time stamp at end End of FFT


// ** Doing Inverse FFT ** //
if (cufftPlan1d(&plan, NX, CUFFT_C2R, BATCH) != CUFFT_SUCCESS){
    fprintf(stderr, "CUFFT error: Plan creation failed"); 
    return; 
}   
if (cufftExecC2R(plan, d_fftout, d_checkdata) != CUFFT_SUCCESS){ 
    fprintf(stderr, "CUFFT error: ExecC2C Forward failed"); 
    return; 
} 
if (cudaDeviceSynchronize() != cudaSuccess){ 
    fprintf(stderr, "Cuda error: Failed to synchronize\n"); 
return; 
} 

// Copying Data Back to Host
cudaMemcpy (h_fftout, d_fftout, FFT_OUT_SIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy (h_checkdata, d_checkdata, ARRAY_SIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cufftDestroy(plan); 
cudaFree(d_rawdata);
cudaFree(d_fftout);

printf("\n");
// Displaying the resulting array
for (int i =0; i < 12 ; i++) {
    printf("%f", h_checkdata[i]/NX);
    printf(((i % 4) != 3) ? "\t" : "\n");
}

/// Ticks conversion    

// convert the tick number into the number of seconds
// since the system was started...
starttime.QuadPart = startTick.QuadPart/ticksPerSecond.QuadPart;
endtime.QuadPart = endTick.QuadPart/ticksPerSecond.QuadPart;

//get the number of hours
int starthours = starttime.QuadPart/3600;
int endhours = endtime.QuadPart/3600;

//get the number of minutes
starttime.QuadPart = starttime.QuadPart - (starthours * 3600);
endtime.QuadPart = endtime.QuadPart - (endhours * 3600);

int startminutes = starttime.QuadPart/60;
int endminutes = endtime.QuadPart/60;

//get the number of seconds
int startseconds = starttime.QuadPart - (startminutes * 60);
int endseconds = starttime.QuadPart - (endminutes *60);

double ticks_per_micro= (double)ticksPerSecond.QuadPart/1000000;
//printf ("\n div = %f",ticks_per_micro);

//get the number of Microseconds
double startmicroSecondes = (double)((startTick.QuadPart % ticksPerSecond.QuadPart) / ticks_per_micro);
double endmicroSecondes = (double)((endTick.QuadPart % ticksPerSecond.QuadPart) / ticks_per_micro);

printf ("\n FFT Started %d:%d:%d::%.2f",starthours, startminutes, startseconds, startmicroSecondes);
printf ("\n FFT Ended %d:%d:%d::%.2f \n",endhours, endminutes, endseconds, endmicroSecondes);

printf ("\nFFT computation time for %d point DFT: %.2fus \n", NX, endmicroSecondes - startmicroSecondes);
}
```

Comment: I suspect, though I don't have a GeForce handy to confirm, that the performance difference between back-to-back and single runs is due to GeForce GPU power management. If a GeForce GPU is doing little/no work it will go into a low power state. Getting back up to full speed after being in a low power state could conceivably take 100s of us. Running back-to-back you already have it at full speed, so this isn't a problem.

Comment: WDDM command batching can also interfere with producing sane timing results on Windows.  I would start by switching your timing methodology to use `cudaEvent` based timing.

Comment: Thanks @Jez, I looked into your suggestion of GPU power management thing. I checked using GPU monitoring tool and found out that when GPU is running normal it's running at around 300MHz but when I run the code it switches to it's max frequency(~950MHz) so that's why I think it takes much time for the first time.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I followed your suggestion and used the `cudaEvent` Now the timings for a test run at 2048-point dft the cudaEvent timings give me ~50us and the Tick count gives me ~123us. I am not sure which one is correct. Why is it necessary to stop the event after exec not after synch?
Now what I am doing is:  `cudaeventRecord(start); cufftExecR2C(); cudaeventRecord(stop); ` 
Ain't we get the correct result after all is being synchronized or after exec is it all good.
Timing constraints are really important for the task I have to do. So that's why I am so concerned about the timing issue.